# Bit shifting properly from 1 array of values to another array of values kinda hard question

Tags: arrays, vb.net, bit

I'm trying to shift the bits from `old:` to `new:`, If 2 same values are encountered a second time, then it should skip them I guess, that's why first example is broken.

Here is my code:

```
        txtUndoPlaintext.Text = Replace(txtUndoPlaintext.Text, "  ", " ")
        txtUndoPlaintext.Text = txtUndoPlaintext.Text.TrimStart(CChar(" "))
        txtUndoPlaintext.Text = txtUndoPlaintext.Text.TrimEnd(CChar(" "))

        Dim UniqueList() As Byte = Split(txtUndoPlaintext.Text, " ").[Select](Function(n) Byte.Parse(n)).ToArray()


        txtPlainText.Text = Replace(txtPlainText.Text, "  ", " ")
        txtPlainText.Text = txtPlainText.Text.TrimStart(CChar(" "))
        txtPlainText.Text = txtPlainText.Text.TrimEnd(CChar(" "))

        Dim OriginalUniqueList() As Byte = Split(txtPlainText.Text, " ").[Select](Function(n) Byte.Parse(n)).ToArray()

        txtUndoBitMask.Text = Replace(txtUndoBitMask.Text, "  ", " ")
        txtUndoBitMask.Text = txtUndoBitMask.Text.TrimStart(CChar(" "))
        txtUndoBitMask.Text = txtUndoBitMask.Text.TrimEnd(CChar(" "))

        bitmask = Split(txtUndoBitMask.Text, " ").[Select](Function(n) Byte.Parse(n)).ToArray()

       Dim newbitmask() As Byte = Nothing
        Array.Resize(newbitmask, bitmask.Length)
        'Array.Copy(bitmask, newbitmask, bitmask.Length)

        bitmaskCounter = 0

        For i = 0 To UniqueList.Length - 1
            For j = (i + 1) To OriginalUniqueList.Length - 1
                If OriginalUniqueList(i) = UniqueList(j) Then
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j

            'If OriginalUniqueList(i) = UniqueList(i) Then
            ' bitmaskCounter += 1
            ' Continue For
            ' End If

            'If OriginalUniqueList(j) = UniqueList(j) Then
            'bitmaskCounter += 1
            'Continue For
            'End If

            If (j < OriginalUniqueList.Length - 1) AndAlso newbitmask(i) = 1 AndAlso newbitmask(j) = 1 AndAlso bitmask(bitmaskCounter) = 1 Then
                newbitmask(i) = 1
                newbitmask(j) = 1
            ElseIf (j > OriginalUniqueList.Length - 1) AndAlso bitmask(bitmaskCounter) = 1 Then
                newbitmask(i) = 1
            ElseIf (j < OriginalUniqueList.Length - 1) AndAlso OriginalUniqueList(i) = UniqueList(i) Then
                newbitmask(i) = 0
            ElseIf bitmask(bitmaskCounter) = 1 Then
                newbitmask(j) = 1
            End If
            bitmaskCounter += 1
        Next
```

```
Broken Example.

value before: 1 2 1 3 2 4 3 8 2 2 1 3 4 2 1 2
value after:  1 2 4 3 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 8 2 1 2 2

old: 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
new: 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0

2,4 = good
3,8 = bad [this is broken]
7,11 = good
```

Here are good examples that work properly.

```
Good Example.
value before: 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4
value after:  1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3

old: 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
new: 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0

3,4 = good
6,7 = good
```

```
Good Example.

value before: 1 2 1 3 2 3 2 4
value after:  1 2 4 1 2 3 2 3

old: 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 
new: 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1

2,3 = good
3,5 = good
5,7 = good
```

```
Good Example.

value before: 1 2 1 3 2
value after:  1 2 1 2 3

old: 0 0 1 1 0
new: 0 0 1 0 1

2,2 = good
3,4 = good
```

**New Code update**

```
    Private Sub Button11_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button11.Click
        Dim bitmaskCounter As Integer = 0


        Dim UniqueList() As Byte = Split("1 2 1 3 2 4 3 8 2 2 1 3 4 2 1 2", " ").[Select](Function(n) Byte.Parse(n)).ToArray()
        Dim OriginalUniqueList() As Byte = Split("1 2 4 3 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 8 2 1 2 2", " ").[Select](Function(n) Byte.Parse(n)).ToArray()

        Dim TheValues = New List(Of Byte)(UniqueList)
        bitmask = Split("0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0", " ").[Select](Function(n) Byte.Parse(n)).ToArray()

        Dim newbitmask() As Byte = Nothing
        Array.Resize(newbitmask, bitmask.Length)
        'Array.Copy(bitmask, newbitmask, bitmask.Length)

        bitmaskCounter = 0
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim j As Integer = 0

        Dim ignoreOldOffsets As New List(Of Short)
        Dim ignoreNewOffsets As New List(Of Short)

        Dim found As Boolean = False

        While i >= 0
            found = False
            Do While j > 0
                If j = OriginalUniqueList.Length Then Exit Do
                If OriginalUniqueList(j) = UniqueList(i) Then
                    found = True
                    Exit Do
                End If
                j += 1
            Loop

            If bitmaskCounter >= bitmask.Length Then Exit While

            If j = i AndAlso OriginalUniqueList(j) = UniqueList(i) OrElse j = OriginalUniqueList.Length Then
                bitmaskCounter += 1
                ignoreOldOffsets.Add(i)
                ignoreNewOffsets.Add(j)
                j = i + 1
                i += 1
                Continue While
            End If

            If ignoreOldOffsets.Contains(i) AndAlso ignoreNewOffsets.Contains(j) Then
                bitmaskCounter += 1
                j = i
                Continue While
            End If

            'If OriginalUniqueList(j) = UniqueList(j) Then
            'bitmaskCounter += 1
            'Continue For
            'End If
            'newbitmask(i) = 1
            'newbitmask(j) = 1
            'ignoreOffsets.Add(i)
            'ignoreOffsets.Add(j)

            If bitmask(i) = 1 Then
                newbitmask(i) = 1
                newbitmask(j) = 1
                ignoreOldOffsets.Add(i)
                ignoreNewOffsets.Add(j)
            End If
            bitmaskCounter += 1
            i += 1
            j = i
        End While

        'Fixed bits output to textbox.
        txtOutput.Text += "New Bits: "
        For i = 0 To newbitmask.Length - 1
            txtOutput.Text += newbitmask(i) & " "
        Next
        txtOutput.Text += vbCrLf

        'Reset bitmaskCounter.
        bitmaskCounter = 0
    End Sub
```

In the code above

```
old:      0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
new:      0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
i get:    0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: If you're looking for a procedure that shifts all bits in the array, I can write you a .dll in masm. There's an asm instruction that would handle this job perfectly. Also would be very fast.

Comment: Otherwise, bit shifting in VB is performed like this: `shiftedByte = myByte << 1` (shift 1 bit to the left)

Comment: I'm looking to scan the arrays `before & after` and produce a value `new` bitstream using the `old` bitstream. Here is a screenshot with more information. https://i.imgur.com/iYwbFDy.jpg and sorry I need it in vb.net not assembly, but yeah if you can do it for me.. I'll pay you 5$ paypal. I posted also on this forum https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?893968-Bit-shifting-properly-from-1-array-of-values-to-another-array-of-values-kinda-hard-qu

Comment: So, if I understand the logic properly: If the values of _before_ and _after_ differ, find the first occurrence of this value, beginning at that index, in the _after_ array and then put "1"s at those positions?

Comment: yes thats it, also ignore `before` and `after` values if they are the same in the same position.

Comment: Then your first "good" example is incorrect... Shouldn't it be `old: 00011111111 , new: 00001111111` ?

Comment: Did you look at the image it's correct only the shifted values  get 1 bit old values don't get 1 bit ( removed) https://imgur.com/iYwbFDy.jpg

Comment: Yes, I've looked at the image, but I'm a bit confused with the first "good example" in your question - why isn't the result as in my previous comment? Why there are only two bits set in each line?

Comment: you're talking about this old value `1 2 3 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4` the `old bits` are generated at random.. I just need to get new bits out of old bits and new/old values, so old bits have nothing to do with anything. You got discord? or any kind of messenger? You are correct with the bits.. if the equation generated the old bits, but the old bits are random.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/1WER1Uv.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238676/discussion-between-unhandledexception-invalidchar-and-sspoke).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved!!!**

```
    Private Sub Button11_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button11.Click
        Dim bitmaskCounter As Integer = 0


        'Dim UniqueList() As Byte = Split("1 2 1 3 2 4 3 8 2 2 1 3 4 2 1 2", " ").[Select](Function(n) Byte.Parse(n)).ToArray()
        'Dim OriginalUniqueList() As Byte = Split("1 2 4 3 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 8 2 1 2 2", " ").[Select](Function(n) Byte.Parse(n)).ToArray()
        'Dim TheValues = New List(Of Byte)(UniqueList)
        'bitmask = Split("0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0", " ").[Select](Function(n) Byte.Parse(n)).ToArray()

        'Dim UniqueList() As Byte = Split("1 2 3 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4", " ").[Select](Function(n) Byte.Parse(n)).ToArray()
        'Dim OriginalUniqueList() As Byte = Split("1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3", " ").[Select](Function(n) Byte.Parse(n)).ToArray()
        'Dim TheValues = New List(Of Byte)(UniqueList)
        'bitmask = Split("0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0", " ").[Select](Function(n) Byte.Parse(n)).ToArray()

        'Dim UniqueList() As Byte = Split("1 2 1 3 2 3 2 4", " ").[Select](Function(n) Byte.Parse(n)).ToArray()
        'Dim OriginalUniqueList() As Byte = Split("1 2 4 1 2 3 2 3", " ").[Select](Function(n) Byte.Parse(n)).ToArray()
        'Dim TheValues = New List(Of Byte)(UniqueList)
        'bitmask = Split("0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0", " ").[Select](Function(n) Byte.Parse(n)).ToArray()

        Dim UniqueList() As Byte = Split("1 2 1 3 2", " ").[Select](Function(n) Byte.Parse(n)).ToArray()
        Dim OriginalUniqueList() As Byte = Split("1 2 1 2 3", " ").[Select](Function(n) Byte.Parse(n)).ToArray()
        Dim TheValues = New List(Of Byte)(UniqueList)
        bitmask = Split("0 0 1 1 0", " ").[Select](Function(n) Byte.Parse(n)).ToArray()




        Dim newbitmask() As Byte = Nothing
        Array.Resize(newbitmask, bitmask.Length)
        'Array.Copy(bitmask, newbitmask, bitmask.Length)

        bitmaskCounter = 0
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim j As Integer = 0

        Dim found As Boolean = False

        Dim firstDuplicateIndex As Integer = -1
        Dim uniquesFound As New List(Of Byte)

        For k = 0 To UniqueList.Length - 1
            If uniquesFound.Contains(OriginalUniqueList(k)) = False Then
                uniquesFound.Add(OriginalUniqueList(k))
            Else
                firstDuplicateIndex = k
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        Dim offsetsComplete As New List(Of Integer)


        While i >= 0
            i = Array.IndexOf(bitmask, CByte(1), i + 1)
            j = i '(i + 1)
            If i = -1 OrElse UniqueList.Length = i Then Exit While
            found = False
            Do While j >= 0
                If j = OriginalUniqueList.Length Then Exit Do

                If j < firstDuplicateIndex OrElse OriginalUniqueList(j) = UniqueList(j) AndAlso bitmask(j) <> 1 OrElse offsetsComplete.Contains(j) Then
                    j += 1
                    Continue Do
                End If

                If OriginalUniqueList(j) = UniqueList(i) Then
                    found = True
                    Exit Do
                End If
                j += 1
            Loop

            If bitmaskCounter >= bitmask.Length Then Exit While

            If j < bitmask.Length AndAlso bitmask(i) = 1 Then
                newbitmask(j) = 1
                offsetsComplete.Add(j)
            End If

            bitmaskCounter += 1
        End While

        'Fixed bits output to textbox.
        txtOutput.Text += "New Bits A: 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0" & vbNewLine
        txtOutput.Text += "New Bits B: "
        For i = 0 To newbitmask.Length - 1
            txtOutput.Text += newbitmask(i) & " "
        Next
        txtOutput.Text += vbCrLf

        'Reset bitmaskCounter.
        bitmaskCounter = 0
    End Sub
```